# Umbraco: querying latest items

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm a newbie in using Umbraco. The current version I'm using is v7++.
I have changed the rendering engine from MVC to webform as I'm not really good with MVC.

Current Item

1. item A
2. item B
3. item C
4. item D

The current problem I'm facing is to query the latest item under "Current item".
And here is the code I have:

```
annRoot.GetDescendantNodes().OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate);
```

But this line of code will definitely cause some performance issue if there is a huge amount of descendants under the "current item".
Is there a way for me to query directly for the latest item without having to retrieve the whole list of descendant.

Comment: What is a huge amount of descendants?

Comment: probably 10k and above?

Answer (score 0):

If this line of code is used in a Razor macro then you should be able to access the last item directly by using .Last()

```
...OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate).Last();
```

Checkout the 'Traversing' section in this [Dynamic Node Cheat Sheet](http://our.umbraco.org/FileDownload?id=3187) .... 
this is from v4.7 when razor support was initially introduced, but it should all still be relevant.

Comment: Do you guys using lucene for querying for the data?